# Is there a way to connect android device to external printer through Bluetooth?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I need to connect to printer through Bluetooth. Is there a way to do it. Printer I use is `CMP10BT`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to; however, your bigger issue will be generating the output for use with the device.  As there is no printer driver to speak of for Android you'll have to write your own output stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Peerke** is correct. The printer uses rather common ESC/POS standard; you should be able to either find some Java library for this or write your own code to output to printer.

I did similar things for Zebra (CPCL standard) and Blackberry (again, Bluetooth and Java) and found it simple.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bluetooth api in android. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)

With the Bluetooth api you can connect to any Bluetooth device you have including printers. The problem is, that you need to know how to speak to your printer. You have to figure that out. Besides that, I don't see any problem why you can't do this.